# port forwarding works from some devices only

Tags: port-forwarding, webserver

I'm running a simple server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and have configured port forwarding. I'm also behind a vpn.

When I try to contact `myexternalIP_ISP:myport` from the same machine, I get to see the folder in which I started the server and `SimpleHTTPServer` shows a connection from my vpn service provider IP (i.e. an external IP set in a country far far away that is different from myexternalIP_ISP above).

When I try to connect to my server via my phone (`myexternalIP_ISP:myport`, no wifi, same vpn and same vpn IP according to whatsmyip), I get a `connection has timed out` error.

My simple server doesn't show any connection attempts either.

Is there a way to figure out what's going on? Why can't I connect?

My router is a TP-Link Archer D7, my phone an android running cyanogenmod 13, and my server run Debian 8, python 2.7.

**Update**

I did two more trials:

1. Enable remote management of the router - I was able to connect to the router via my phone's 4g connection and vpn
2. Run the calibre book software server - same thing as with the python server: I can use the local machine to connect using the external IP via vpn, however I can't connect via my phone's 4g connection even when using the same vpn

I find this really weird...

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty you are experiencing an issue with your routing - and not one that is your fault - and something that is pretty difficult to fix.   When trying to access the external site from your LAN, your router is not correctly able to intercept the request, rewrite the packet and send it on the correct interface (the from address of the packet will be incorrect) - thus you are unable  to access this site from its external IP address from your LAN.

If you start using DNS, the way around it (and its not easy) is to use split DNS so your LAN gets the LAN IP of the server, and the rest of the world gets the WAN IP. The interesting bit is running 2 nameservers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can access the server from the same machine on which it is running using the external IP. However I can't access it from my phone using the data connection. Curiously I can connect to the router itself from the phone if I allow remote management of the router.... After that I tried running the calibre server, however the same thing happens there, i.e. I can use the local machine to connect remotely via a vpn but cannot connect to it when I use my phone's 4g connection via the same vpn.... I'll update my question to add the new information

Comment: If you can't access it from your phone when your phone is not connected to your LAN, something is wrong with the port forwarding in the router - and indeed it may be that the management of the router is conflicting with your ability to map that port to your computer.

Comment: Hmm, I might try a few other ports... I just think it's odd since both request should come from the same remote vpn server. So it's just not clear to me how it can be that one is going through, showing the external ip of the vpn, and the other one doesn't make it through the router....